# parse string of numbers with +/- signs and keep signs

Tags: python, string

I have a string that looks like this

```
+0.6810+0.0266-0.0140-0.0111-0.0080-00.026-0.0229+000.84
```

I need to parse this string at each +/- sign and while at the same time keeping the signs with the numbers so that they can be stored into variables. So what I want to have come out are varialbes for each of seven positive or negative numbers like

```
a= 0.6810
b= 0.0266
c= -0.0140
```

etc

I am able to spit the string but now now a way converting to a flow and keeping the sign
current code to split string is:

```
print (re.split(r'[+-]+',dataString))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` on your string: -

```
>>> string = "+0.6810+0.0266-0.0140-0.0111-0.0080-00.026-0.0229+000.84"
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> matches = re.findall(r'[-+]\d+\.\d+', string)
>>> matches
['+0.6810', '+0.0266', '-0.0140', '-0.0111', '-0.0080', '-00.026', '-0.0229', 
 '+000.84']
>>>
>>> a = float(matches[0])
>>> 0.681

>>> (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) = map(float, matches)[:7]
```

Comment: thanks for the great response.  Basic question here.  I am using aptna studio pyDev for writing these scripts.  It seams like the format u post is entering a command and seeing the generated response command line style.  What sort of environment do you use?

Comment: `a,b,c,d,e,f,g=map(float,re.findall(r'[+-]\d+.\d+',strs))[:7]` is better, it's merely a coincidence that our solutions are almost identical. :) .So time to delete mine.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Ah! That makes it so simple.. Let me try :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Man. Thats great.

Answer (score 3):

If the string is like the one you posted you can simply do something like:

```
your_string.replace('-', '+-').split('+')
```

But this is not robust.

Anyway you could simply use the `re.findall` method. I think:

```
re.findall(r'[+-]\d+(\.\d+)?', your_string)
```

should do the trick.

Actually it would also match integers, if your numbers always have the period and digits on both sites you can use:

```
r'[+-]\d+\.\d+
```

Comment: this is the best solution. (a slight plus-up from Ashwini Chaudhary's below, and 100 plus-ups from mine!)

Answer (score 0):

What about a string replace with a split? Something like

```
print (re.replace(r"([+-])", " \1", dataString)).split()
```

Might not be the best way, but it'll do the job...I think, didn't test it!